# jquery hover with css dropdown menu out of position on page load

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have a CSS dropdown menu using an unordered list, and using the jQuery hover method:
It's working well, except for when the user puts the cursor over the element that is bound to the hover while the page is loading.

When this happens, the dropdown is shown out of position when the cursor leaves the "hover" area.
When the cursor is brought back into the hover area, the menu returns to its original position.

Ie

Fruits    Vegetables
 apples     carrots
 pears      beets

---

User hovers over fruits, and menu drops down in correct position.
If user places cursor back over "Fruits" while page is loading, the drop down next appears out of position, when the cursor leaves "Fruits". Moving off "Fruits" and then back to "Fruits", the menu is repositioned correctly.

---

I've tried wrapping everything with $(document).ready, thinking that might help since this seems to happen only if the menu option is moused over DURING page load. No luck.

---

Here is the jquery call I'm making:

```
$("ul.dropdown li.navMainFmt").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("hover");
    $('ul:first',this).fadeIn();
```

//  }, function(){

```
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
$('ul:first',this).toggle();
```

});

---

I did search stackoverflow for an answer, but am not quite sure how to phrase the question.
Any ideas or posts to previous solutions are appreciated.

Comment: Google `jquery hover Intent`

Comment: fiddle would be easy to understand your issues. The jquery you provided here seems to be working fine.

Comment: It looks like hoverIntent plugin solves this issue. thank you Atif.